# Use of deleted Function when pushing class object to std::vector?

Tags: c++, class, vector

I have two classes as shown below.
When i try to populate a vector of Entity objects in the Spawner Entity class,it gives me this error

```
error: use of deleted function 'Entity::Entity(Entity&&)'
```

I cant figure out why it wont call the constructor and push the class object on the vector
Also, I Have inherited the Entity Class in the Spawner Entity

Entity.h

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<SFML/Window.hpp>
#include<SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class Entity
{
private:
  sf::RenderWindow win;
  sf::RectangleShape enemy;


public:
  Entity();
  void InitializeEntity();
  void Update(const float* DeltaTime);
  void Render(sf::RenderWindow& mWindow);
};
```

Entity.cpp

```
Entity::Entity()
{
  InitializeEntity();
}

void Entity::InitializeEntity()
{
  enemy.setPosition(rand()%255+1,rand()%255+1);
  enemy.move(rand()%255+1,rand()%255+1);
  enemy.setSize(sf::Vector2f(50.f,50.f));
  sf::Color color(rand()%255+1,rand()%255+1,rand()%255+1);
  enemy.setFillColor(color);
  enemy.setOutlineColor(sf::Color::White);
  enemy.setOutlineThickness(2.f);
}



void Entity::Render(sf::RenderWindow& mWindow)
{
  mWindow.draw(enemy);
}
```

SpawnerEntity.h

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<SFML/Window.hpp>
#include<SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "Entity.h"

class SpawnerEntity:public Entity
{
private:
  float SpawnTimer;
  float SpawnTimerMax;
  int MaxEnemies;
  bool done;

  //std::vector<Entity> SpawnedEnemies;

public:
  SpawnerEntity();
  void InitializeEntity();
  void SpawnSubEntities(std::vector<Entity> &enemies);
  bool CheckSpawnDone();
};
```

SpawnerEntity.cpp

```
#include "SpawnerEntity.h"

SpawnerEntity::SpawnerEntity()
{
  SpawnTimerMax=1.f;
  SpawnTimer=SpawnTimerMax;
  MaxEnemies=10;
  done=false;
}

bool SpawnerEntity::CheckSpawnDone()
{
  return done;
}

void SpawnerEntity::SpawnSubEntities(std::vector<Entity> &enemies)
{
    for(int i=0;i<MaxEnemies;i++)
    {
        std::cout << "SPAWNED" << '\n';
        enemies.push_back(Entity());     //this line here gives me the above error
    }
    done=true;
}
```

Comment: Probably because some member variable of `Entity` makes it non-movable. Please post the definition of `Entity`.

Comment: Hello,I have updated the post with the class definitions

Comment: Why does every entity have a `sf::RenderWindow` (which they never use)? Those can't be copied, and it doesn't make much sense to give every entity their own window.

Comment: oh shoot! you are right, i must have written it when instead i wanted to pass window as a reference,ill try to run it without that

Comment: Additionally you should add a move constructor. Currently your temporary objects are copied.

Comment: @jabaa also i will look into adding the move constructor as well after i read more about copy and move constructors,but a short explanation here would be great ,if not too much to ask :P

Comment: A move constructor allows `std::vector` to move your objects into the vector. This means that all members are also moved. A move operation is usually faster than a copy operation. In a move constructor you usually don't copy memory but redirect pointers. Currently you are creating and initializing a temporary, copying it into the vector and deleting it after the `push_back`. Obviously the copy is not necessary. You could either `emplace_back` a new object in-place in the vector or move the temporary.

Comment: Usually this is an unnecessary micro optimization and I wouldn't mention it but since this is game development and you're using `float` instead of `double` you probably want to optimize your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot you guys, i was pulling my hair only to find out the error was so trivial,also thanks @jabba